# Getting size of Gtk.Table in python

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am having a problem with widget Gtk.Table - I would like to know, if there is a way how to get a current size of the table (number of rows and columns).

Thank you, very much for help, Tomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to access the [properties](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtktable.html#properties-gtktable) `n-columns` and `n-rows`.

You can do this using:

```
cols = mytable.get_property('n-columns')
rows = mytable.get_property('n-rows')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read GTK properties:

```
t = gtk.Table(myNumberOfRows, myNumberofCols)
t.get_property("n-rows") # number of rows in the table
t.get_property("n-columns") # number of cols in the table
```

Answer (score 0):

In most recent versions of PyGTK you can get/set those values via `table.props.n_columns` and `table.props.n_rows`, which is synonymous with the `get_property()` (mentioned in the other answers) and `set_property()` methods.